# DatabaseConnection datasource creation from eclipse

Tags: database, eclipse, web-applications, glassfish-3

I am new to Eclipse.
Currently developing a sample web application using primefaces 3.1 and glassfish 3.

I have created a oracle database connection under datasource explorer. I would like to know how to 
integrate this with my web application, so that I could connect to database from my web application. I know that by creating context.xml and entering the following might be suffice for database access, but are there anyways to integrate database connection with my application? So that I do not need to hard code password in context.xml.

I have used Jdeveloper in the past and by creating a database connection corresponding datasource entries in xml are generated. So I was wondering something similar would be possible using Eclipse?

Any help is highly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
   <Resource name="jdbc/SampleDB" auth="Container"
       type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
       username="app" password="app"
       driverClassName="org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"
       url="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample" 
       maxActive="8"    /> 
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to create datasource for glassfish.

I created a a JDBC Resource under GlassFish and pointed connection to my connection created under Date Source Explorer. It created a `sun-resources.xml`. I had to manually rename this to `glassfish-resource.xml`. By default there are no entry for password,so I had to manually add . When I ran my web application I was getting this error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: No PasswordCredential found
```

So to resolve this error I added a property in JDBC Connection Pool in glassfish admin server. Now I could connect to Oracle database.

Not sure why I have to do two steps manually. Besides by default it creates `sun-resources.xml`. Perhaps someone could point out how to workaround these.

Thanks